# Origin of "It is the long history of humankind that those who learned to collaborate and improvise most effectively have prevailed”?

Tags: etymology

I am looking for the source of the quote

> It is the long history of humankind (and animal kind, too) that those
> who learned to collaborate and improvise most effectively have
> prevailed

A search online indicates it derives from Charles Darwin's 'On the Origin of Species ' in 1859, and that it may have been paraphrased. Yet, I cannot find which section of the book it might derive from.

Could anyone suggest a source and page number?

Comment: Curiously the sentence appears to have become  popular from th 90’s. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=those+who+learned+to+collaborate%2C+learned+to+collaborate+and+improvise+&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthose%20who%20learned%20to%20collaborate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearned%20to%20collaborate%20and%20improvise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is literature orientated, not grammar / word- / expression-usage etc.

Comment: Humankind? Charles Darwin? I think not, man!

Comment: @user121863 - oddly your answer didn't appear on my page until I'd posted the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Darwin Correspondence Project](https://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/people/about-darwin/six-things-darwin-never-said#quote3) (Cambridge University) it is not a quote from Darwin:

> In the long history of humankind (and animal kind, too) those who learned to collaborate and improvise most effectively have prevailed.

> Supposedly from Descent of Man . So far no one has found where it really comes from – but it definitely isn't Darwin.

Comment: The results of the search term "collaborate and improvise" in Google Ngrams from 1800 to 1900 show no results at all! I should not have been surprised - the phrase seems far more modern. "https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=collaborate+and+improvise&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3